# Xquery/Xpath Function for attribute name value

Tags: xpath, xquery

I am trying to write a xquery to get the value for selected names.
Below is the request I have
i.e. for name = StartDate I want to get the value or StartDate only

```
<associatedDates>
Zero or more repetitions:-->
<com1:date name="StartDate" value="StartDateValue"/
<com1:date name="DueDate" value="DueDateValue"/>
<com1:date name="SchedStartDate" value="2017-10-23T00:00:00.000-04:00"/>
 </associatedDates>
```

I tried all different xqueries. But what I get is all dates assigned to a single variable in my result.

Comment: You didn't show us any XQuery you tried. And your XML snippet isn't even well-formed XML. Please be more precise when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a predicate to constrain the XPath to the right element, and select its `value` attribute:

```
/associatedDates/com1:date[@name = 'DueDate']/@value
```

Comment: Thanks so much. that worked.. Accidentally I was using one extra '/' before @name. /associatedDates/com1:date/[@name = 'DueDate']/@value